# Snowflake use variable as a filename while unloading data to S3

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I believe the problem is not specific to unloading data to S3, but how can we use variables in the names.

I open an S3 stage as following

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE s3_stage
    URL = 's3://some-foo-bar-url'
    CREDENTIALS = (aws_role='arn:aws:iam::<some-number>:role/<some-foo-bar-role-with-relevant-permissions>')
;
```

Then I want to use it to unload my table data as

```
SET DATE_TODAY = TO_DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2));

COPY INTO @crm.s3_stage/toProcess/{$TODAY_DATE}/restaurants
FROM (my_restaurants_table)
    file_format = (FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"')
    include_query_id = TRUE
    header = TRUE
    max_file_size = 2000000
;
```

I want to $TODAY_DATE in S3 bucket's directory path

What should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use a Stored Procedure / Snowflake Scripting, the below works

```
execute immediate
$$
declare
  date_today varchar default TO_DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2));
  copy_into varchar default 'COPY INTO @<stage>/' || date_today || '/filename FROM (select * from <table> limit 10) overwrite = true';
begin
  execute immediate :copy_into;
  return date_today;
end;
$$;
```